# ¿Cuál sería la traducción de "strunk" al español?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos, solicitud-de-término

La palabra ***strunk*** no existe en el idioma inglés, lo cual complica una traducción directa. Más bien sería un modismo (¿americano?), y buscando en la red alguna referencia me encontré con [esta](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/strunk) que realmente no estoy seguro que sea oficial:

> Estar bajo la influencia de marihuana y alcohol al mismo tiempo. Contracción de "stoned" (drogado) y "drunk" (ebrio).

¿Esta información es correcta? De ser así, ¿cuál podría ser su posible traducción?

Comment: Los portmanteaus son muy comunes en inglés, pero menos en español.  Colocado refiere tanto al alcohol como a las drogas, pero es una O y no una Y (además de usarse solo en España por lo que tengo entendido).  Simplemente diría «borracho y drogado» o tal vez «embriagado de alcohol y drogas»

Comment: ¿Droguebrio? :-D

Comment: @CarlosAlejo jajaja buena idea :D Platicando con unos colegas del trabajo me dijeron que pudiese ser *pachipedo*, (lo sé, se escucha y se lee horrible y no sé si ponerlo como edición a la pregunta o una posible respuesta), pero solo aplicaría para México, algo muy local y aparte no sé si sea general para todo el pais, realmente estaba buscando algo muy general que se pudiera entender para cualquier hispano parlante.

Comment: Buena la de "droguebrio". Les ofrezco _narcorracho_.

Answer (score 3):

Con mucha frecuencia intentamos construir palabras de forma análoga a cómo se hace en inglés. Esto es, juntando las dos palabras para construir una nueva que se entienda relativamente por el contexto: *smog* (*smoke* + *fog*) es de las más antiguas, *Spanglish* (*Spanish* + *English*) de origen más cercano, etc.

Las lenguas germánicas, a las que pertenece el inglés, tienden a unir palabras para que se expliquen por sí solas. Además, suelen ser más ágiles a la hora de incorporarlas. Las lenguas románicas, por contra, tienden más a combinarlas para dar significados, a menos que haya raíces latinas o griegas fácilmente utilizables.

Por eso, yo creo que buscar alguna combinación de "drogado" y "bebido" puede dar propuestas curiosas como la que [apunta Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20212/cu%C3%A1l-ser%C3%ADa-la-traducci%C3%B3n-de-strunk-al-espa%C3%B1ol#comment30598_20212) de *droguebrio*. Yo sugeriría también *colorracho* o cosas así. Pero lo más coherente probablemente consiste en explicar el concepto con un término del tipo:

- drogado y borracho
- drogado y ebrio
- colocado y borracho

Y si en el futuro alguien da con una opción que efectivamente combina las dos palabras en una, pues se adopta sin problema.

Comment: ¿Sabías que para *smog* la RAE recoge tanto la adaptación fonética _[esmog](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GRwQzXC)_ como la traducción _[neblumo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QJu0NKk)_ (neblina+humo)?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¡anda! Esto _no_ ayuda a mi argumentación de que las lenguas románicas no tienden a hacer este tipo de uniones de palabras :)

Comment: Yo creo que sí que las hacemos, solo que en la mayoría de los casos no pasan de la expresión oral, y solo en contadas ocasiones llegan a tener la suficiente acogida como para pasar a la lengua escrita y acabar en el diccionario.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo cierto. Probablemente el problema en todo esto reside en que solemos comparar el inglés hablado coloquial con el español escrito aceptado por la RAE. Trasladar el español coloquial aquí sería interesante, si bien sería muy difícilmente contrastable (_resulta que en un pueblo de Cuenca dicen X..._). Por tanto, esta peticiones de traducción de términos ingleses coloquiales serán complicadas en la mayoría de casos.

Comment: @fedorqui le he buscado por diferentes lados y no logro encontrar una traducción que me satisfaga. Ahora verás, todo el meollo de este asunto es para realizar la traduccion del nombre de la medalla [Strunk & White](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) de [es.so], a lo mejor y con tu ayuda logremos dar una traducción y significado a esa medalla, a lo mejor y nisiquiera tiene que ver con la sugerencia que puse en mi pregunta inicialmente.

Comment: @Flxtr bueno pero fíjate que el nombre de la medalla viene por el libro [The Elements of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style) escrito por dos señores: Strunk y White. Por tanto, lo que estarías intentando es traducir unos apellidos. Probablemente sería cuestión de abordarlo diferentemente: encontrar una obra de referencia parecida y conocida en todas las zonas de habla hispana. Se me ocurre el _Libro de estilo_ :)

Comment: ¡Vaya! Me has dejado atónito, no sabía que por eso era el nombre de la etiqueta, eso cambia el sentido de todo. *Libro de estilo* me suena bien pero no estoy seguro que ses muy bien aceptado en la comunidad, talvés lo mejor será dejar esa etiqueta tal y como está, ¿qué opinas?

Comment: @Flxtr  Yo creo que sería interesante encontrar algo más comprensible, pues como hemos visto aquí lo de _Strunk & White_ no es demasiado conocido. Probablemente sea un tema a abordar en Meta de [es.so].

Answer (score 1):

En Mexico le dicen "Pedo". This is not a formal translation as "Pedo" is slang.

Comment: *Pedo* se utiliza únicamente cuando estás ebrio, el punto es encontrar el término adecuado cuando estás drogado y ebrio al mismo tiempo :)

Comment: @Flxtr pues no te creas. "Ir pedo" es una expresión que se usa también en España. La RAE le da como [cuarta acepción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SJF2rm9) "ebrio, bajo los efectos del alcohol **o de otra droga**". Y cita como ejemplo: _Volvió de la fiesta pedo perdido._ En esa frase, pues, la intoxicación podría ser por alcohol, por drogas, o incluso puede que ambas. Lo malo es que el término queda ambiguo al no saber qué tipo de intoxicación lleva el que va "pedo".

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¡vaya! eso es nuevo para mí, no sabía que se utilizara esa misma palabra con ese significado en otros países, hoy he aprendido algo nuevo :D